# How to move/copy shared build scheme to .xcworkspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, teamcity

By default shared build schemes are stored in .xcodeproject. However, Teamcity expect them in .xcworkspace. And they are really should be there. How do I set my workspace so they stored there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the Manage Schemes dialog in Xcode. Click the drop down for the container of the scheme. Change it from the project to the workspace.
[image]